# QTimer dont stop when windows is closed

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I am currently starting on QTCreator. I have been asked to use QTimers in a particular context which is this:

We have an open window,
One or more QTimers are triggered and make things appear on the screen every x msec.
When we press "Escape" the window should close and everything should be reset to 0.

But here is the problem, the timers are defined in a static way:

```
QTimer::singleShot(500, this, SLOT(foo());
```

When I call `this->close()` (which closes my window), the timers do not stop and continue. I tried several solutions: browse all the QTimers contained in my object, obviously there are none since they are defined in static. Instead of declaring them in static I've  tried to create each time a new QTimer object like that:

```
    QTimer *timer= new QTimer(this);
    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    timer->setInterval(2000);
    timer->setParent(this);
    timer->start();
```

And then call timer->stop() later, but I think it's very brutal when you have multiple Timers in the same code.

Is there a way to stop the timers when `this->close` is called, knowing that the timers are defined as a static one ?

Comment: If you make your QTimer object a child of the window (which `new QTimer(this)` does do, assuming that `this` is your window object), then the QTimer will be automtically deleted (and therefore stopped) when then window is deleted.  Most likely your window is not being deleted after the `close()` call; is that intentional?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I've asked this to myself, when this->close() (this is my window object) how should I do to "destroy" it correctly and not only close it

Comment: You can call setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose) on your window to have Qt automatically delete it when the user closes it, or you could override the ‘void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)’ method and call ‘deleteLater()’ from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using,

```
QWindow *qw = new QWindow();
QTimer *timer= new QTimer();
```

To solve the issue you need to connect destroyed() signal of QWindow to timer's slot stop()
So as soon as window is destroyed all registered timers will be stopped without explicit stop call. make sure you connect all timer instances. Code snippet as following,

```
QObject::connect(&qw, SIGNAL(destroyed()), timer, SLOT(stop()))
QObject::connect(&qw, SIGNAL(destroyed()), timer2, SLOT(stop()))
QObject::connect(&qw, SIGNAL(destroyed()), timer3, SLOT(stop()))
```

PS:

```
QTimer *timer= new QTimer(this); // here you are setting parent as 'this' already
timer->setSingleShot(true);
timer->setInterval(2000);
timer->setParent(this); // remove this, no need to set parent again.
timer->start();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot !! Seems to wors fine. Can you please explain me briefly what's the difference when windows is destroyed and closed ? Does this->stop() emit a destroyed() signal when triggered ?

Comment: @nathaaan yes exactly destroyed() is a signal from QObject (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) since QWindow is a QObject it will trigger destroyed signal on close as it is getting destroyed.